# nodejs oracle improve ability

Tags: node.js, express, oracle11gr2

i am using node-oracleDB connector to connect to my local database , and i want to ask if it was an other(optimal) way to connect to the database, in order to improve communication ability between nodejs and oracle. thanks

Comment: What exactly are you asking?  Please explain more.

Comment: @RachedNemr Do you use connection pooling?

Answer (score 1):

I think using connection pooling is the good way. You can find some examples of pooling at [here](https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/tree/master/test).

Please look at this file https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/blob/master/test/pool.js and read carefully to understand how handling connections in a pool.

Comment: Please explain what your link covers.  Answers should be able to live without relying on an external link.

Comment: Yeah, please read carefully this link https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/blob/master/test/pool.js

Comment: To understand how to handle connection in a pool.

Comment: That information needs to be in your answer, not in the comments.  Please expand on your answer by making an edit instead of including just a link.

Answer (score 0):

Node-oracledb is the connector to use when writing Node.js applications that need to connect to Oracle Database.

Most apps will want to use a [connection pool](https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/blob/master/doc/api.md#connpooling)

```
var oracledb = require('oracledb');

oracledb.createPool (
  {
    user          : "hr"
    password      : "welcome"
    connectString : "localhost/XE"
  },
  function(err, pool)
  {
    pool.getConnection (
      function(err, connection)
      {
        // use the connection
        connection.execute(. . .

          // release the connection when finished
          connection.close(
            function(err)
            {
              if (err) { console.error(err.message); }
            });
          });
      });
  });
```

There are some simplifications such as the 'default' connection pool that make it easier to share a pool across different modules.  This is all covered in the [documentation](https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/blob/master/doc/api.md#connpooling).